# How to model bind nested views in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I am struggling in getting my head around how to model bind nested views within xamarin and MVVM.
The idea is to make a custom control. This will then be on a view. This will be in a page.

I have created a basic project with some buttons to try and get it working. The page has a dynamic grid. So in the code behind it loops through and generates the view. The page also has a "SelectedView" property. When a button is clicked I want to be able to update this property so I could update some information on the page.

Here is my code to help give an idea to what I am doing (I maybe thinking about this wrong).

**Page**

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**Code behind**

```
 LabelPageViewModel VM { get; set; }
        public LabelPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            VM = new LabelPageViewModel();
            VM.InitiliseGridContent();
            BindingContext = VM;

            grid.RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection();
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Star });
            }

            grid.ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Star });
            }

            int listValue = 0;

            for(int i = 0;i <4; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    grid.Children.Add(VM.GridViewList[listValue],j,i);
                    listValue = listValue + 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

**ViewModel**

```
 public ObservableCollection<CustomButtonGridView> GridViewList { get; set; }

public CustomButtonGridView selectedView;
public CustomButtonGridView SelectedView
{
    get { return selectedView; }
    set
    {
        if(selectedView != value)
        {
            selectedView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

Color backgroundColor;
public Color BackgroundColor
{
    get
    {
        return  backgroundColor; 
    }
    set
    {
        if(backgroundColor!= value)
        {
            backgroundColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public LabelPageViewModel()
{

}

public void InitiliseGridContent()
{
    GridViewList = new ObservableCollection<CustomButtonGridView>();

    //Loop through and create blank items.
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        GridViewList.Add(new CustomButtonGridView(this));
    }

    SelectedView = GridViewList[0];
}


public ICommand BtnCmd
{
    get { return new Command<CustomButtonGridView>(async (x) => await ButtonClicked(x)); }
}

async Task ButtonClicked(CustomButtonGridView model)
{
    SelectedView = model;

    foreach(var item in GridViewList)
    {
        if(item != SelectedView)
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
        }
        
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
        <buttonView:CustomButtonView x:Name="myButton"
                                     Command="{Binding BtnCmd}"
                                     CommandParameter="{x:Reference myContent}" Text="Button"
                                     BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}"></buttonView:CustomButtonView>
    </Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
  ButtonGridViewModel VM { get; set; }
    
    
            LabelPageViewModel labelVM { get; set; }
    
            public CustomButtonGridView(LabelPageViewModel vm)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                labelVM = vm;
                BindingContext = labelVM;
    
                grid.RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection();
                
                grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Star });
            }
    
            public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedCommandProperty =
           BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SelectCmd), typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomButtonGridView), null);
    
            public ICommand SelectCmd
            {
                get => (ICommand)GetValue(SelectedCommandProperty);
                set
                {
                    SetValue(SelectedCommandProperty, value);
                    labelVM.selectedView = this;
    
                }
            }
    
            public static void Execute(ICommand command)
            {
                if (command == null) return;
                if (command.CanExecute(null))
                {
                    command.Execute(null);
                }
            }
    
            // this is the command that gets bound by the control in the view
            // (ie. a Button, TapRecognizer, or MR.Gestures)
            public Command OnTap => new Command(() => Execute(SelectCmd));
```

**ViewModel**

```
 public ICommand BtnCmd
            {
                get { return new Command(async () => await ButtonClicked()); }
            }
    
            async Task ButtonClicked()
            {
                Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Clicked", "Clicked", "OK");
            }
    
            public Color selectedColor;
            public Color SelectedColor
            {
                get { return selectedColor; }
                set
                {
                    if(selectedColor != value)
                    {
                        selectedColor = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Control**

```
public class CustomButtonView : Button
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CustomTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("CustomText", typeof(string), typeof(CustomButtonView), "Default");
    public string CustomText
    {
        get { return (string)base.GetValue(CustomTextProperty); }
        set 
        { 
            base.SetValue(CustomTextProperty, value);
            Text = value;
        }
    }

    public CustomButtonView()
    {
        Text = CustomText;
    }
}
```

On my page I have a list of the Views. I then loop through and create 16 items on a 4X4 grid.
I set the first item to be the selected item.

On my View I have my custom button where I could add it's property bindings etc.

I then have a click event in the view that fires an alert. I want to change the color of the clicked button as a proof of concept. Currently all buttons turn red as none of them are marked as the "selectedItem".

**What I am trying to achieve**
Button is clicked on control -> notifies view -> notifies Page

The button can do an action. The view could do some logic. The page could do some logic based on button pressed.

I am not sure how to glue together multiple views and view models to get them to bind correctly. Maybe some kind of 2 way binding I am missing?

I might be thinking about this wrong and there might be a better way to achieve what I want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: The code you upload does not specify the corresponding class name, which makes it a little difficult to understand the logic between them.   What's the last `ViewModel` is used for?  If it is convinient for you ,could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Hi I have uploaded my basic test project to github at https://github.com/developerfiveneosoftware/xamarin-nested-binding

I started a new xamarin app and then pointed the shell to just run my page. 
I have a "CustomButtonPage.xaml" that loads a "CustomButtonGridView". The CustomButtonGridView Contains a "CustomButtonView".

I am trying to get my head around how to glue multiple views together correctly in MVVM. (I might be going about it with the viewmodels etc wrong?). 

Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: You can try  `CollectionView` which is easy to achieve this funciton.For more details, check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction .

Comment: Awesome thanks this looks like the kind of thing I was after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you can try [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction) which is easy to achieve this funciton.

`CollectionView` is a view for presenting lists of data using different layout specifications. It aims to provide a more flexible, and performant alternative to `ListView`.

`CollectionView` should be used for presenting lists of data that require scrolling or selection. A bindable layout can be used when the data to be displayed doesn't require scrolling or selection.

The result is like this:

[image]

For more , check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction .